Cannot start kafka testcontainer with confluentinc/confluent-local:7.5.0
I can't run kafka testcontainer using the kafka module of testcontainers/testcontainers-go. But I can boot up a kafka with the same image using GenericContainer. The weird part is, when I send below to a colleague with the same computer, they can run it without any problems.
I made sure there are no processes listening on ports I allocate for kafka before running. I also tried extending the context deadline and changing the wait timeouts of the kafka testcontainer. Tried giving my docker 15gb of ram, did not solve the issue also.
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    kafkaContainer, err := kafka.RunContainer(ctx,
        kafka.WithClusterID("test-cluster"),
        testcontainers.WithImage("confluentinc/confluent-local:7.5.0"),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Kafka is running")

    time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)

    // Clean up the container after
    defer func() {
        if err := kafkaContainer.Terminate(ctx); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to terminate container: %s", err)
        }
    }()
}


...
 Creating container for image confluentinc/confluent-local:7.5.0
✅ Container created: b6c3b701c2fa
 Starting container: b6c3b701c2fa
✅ Container started: b6c3b701c2fa
port not found
context deadline exceeded
...

